# Правильно ли говорить "очень согласна"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Сегодня услышала словосочетание "очень согласна" - правильно ли это?
Можно ли быть очень согласной?
Мне кажется, что можно быть либо согласным, либо нет, а очень - это что-то вроде сильно беременна...

Answer (score 2):

Очень согласен - неверное выражение.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Очень - это наречие степени, а степень согласия по конкретному вопросу обозначить сложно. С другой стороны, часто обсуждается пакет вопросов.

Обычно люди соглашаются  с одними предложениями, но не готовы принять другие. В этом случае говорят, что они не совсем согласны, еще есть вопросы для обсуждения.

Если же достигнуто полное взаимопонимание, то это обозначается как "вполне согласен".

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "очень согласна" с точки зрения холодного рассудка не правильно, но на эмоциональном фоне сказать можно всё, что угодно:) Не судите строго эту учительницу, она же женщина:)

Answer (score 1):

Можно сказать: вполне согласен и не совсем согласен. А вариант "очень согласна" неправилен.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение вполне возможно в разговорной речи. Очень согласен, очень правильно, очень верно и т.п.

Comment: а, если это произносит "бывший учитель русского языка", а ныне сотрудник министерства образования, по TV, да еще 1 сентября...(((
тогда можно?

Comment: Ну и что же, что по ТВ... И при чем тут 1 сентября? Повторяю, в разговорной речи вполне возможно. Эмоциональная разговорная фраза.

Answer (score 0):

Я предлогаю такой вариант, где подобное сочитание можно допустить: "Я согласна, я даже очень согласна!" Хотя сам по себе, без всплеска эмоций, этот вариант никуда не годится, но "вполне согласна" не может выразить всей радости (или сарказма) - там есть лишь удовлетворение.

Comment: Я с Вами совершенно согласна))) - вариант "очень согласна" никуда не годится, особенно, если учесть тот факт, что услышала я его из уст преподавателя русского языка(((

Comment: Преподаватели русского языка не используют разговорную речь? Даже академики не гнушаются. Странные у вас представления.

Comment: Niemand, а что значит преподаватели не используют разговорную речь? Они что, разговаривают на книжном языке? Разговорная речь не выходит за рамки литературного языка.

Comment: Так я об этом и спрашиваю автора вопроса. Нормальная разговорная фраза же, чем она может не нравиться?

Comment: Выражение очень согласен - неправильное. Нельзя быть согласным в какой-то степени. Тогда можно употребить синонимы: безгранично, весьма, крайне.
Понятие <<очень, весьма>> в прилагательных выражается:
1) превосходной степенью: высочайшая гора, глупейший роман, малейшая ошибка, новейшие изобретения. Вообразите себе маленького человека с... длиннейшими рыжими усами. Тург.;
2) приставкой <<наи>>- и словом <<самый>> при превосходной степени: наибольший, наименьший, наилучший, наискорейший; самый лучший, самый что ни на есть модный;

Comment: 3) Приставкой <<все->>: всевышний, вселюбезный, всепокорный, всеславный; при превосх. ст. всемилостивейший, всенижайший, всеподданейший, всепреданнейший; 4) приставкой <<пре->>: преблагий, превечный, прегрешный, предобрый, премудрый, преуморительнейший, пренеприятный;
5) приставкой <<раз->> («рас-: развеселый, разлюбезный, разудалый, распрекрасный, распроклятый. <Да ведь шапка бобровая! — Хоть разбобровая, так не куплю. (Ирон.: распронаикультурнейший);

Comment: 6) приставкой <<высоко->>: высокоименитый, высокопочтенный, высокоталантливый; высокоторжественный, высокочтимый, высокоуважаемый (иногда: глубокоуважаемый);
7) приставкой <<много->>: многоуважаемый, многотерпеливый, многотрудный;
8) приставкой <<тре->> только в словах: трегубительный, треклятый; треволнения.

Comment: В наречиях понятие <<очень>> выражается всеми этими способами (с соответствующим изменением окончания) и кроме того формами вроде: давным-давно, полным-полно, черным-черно; крепко-накрепко, перво-наперво, просто-напросто; белым-набело, бедным-набедно, грешным-нагрешно, густым-нагусто, дивным-надивно и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Это не разговорная речь, а речевая ошибка. Ещё можно услышать"очень прекрасно". Уже прекрасно, куда же лучше?

Comment: Вы правы, Злата - речевая ошибка! И ничто иное!